# Python: how best to discover common indices faster?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, bigdata, processing-efficiency

I came up with the following approach for finding all common indices in which values are *present* across two vectors of equal length. I love the readability of this but I need for it to be faster...

```
missingA = np.argwhere(np.isnan(vectorA)==True);
missingA = [missingA[ma][0] for ma in range(len(missingA))];

missingB = np.argwhere(np.isnan(vectorB)==True);
missingB = [missingB[mb][0] for mb in range(len(missingB))];

allmissidxs = set(missingA).union(set(missingB)); 
idxs = [idx for idx in range(len(vectorA))   if idx not in allmissidxs];
```

It most definitely works, but the vectors I need to use it on are anywhere from 1Million to 3Million elements each...and potentially needs to be run multiple times. I'm using "...if idx not in allmissidxs" as opposed to say "...if idx in allpresidxs" since missing values are sure to be far smaller subset to sweep through. Also, I'm sure it doesn't help that missingA and missingB have to be reconfigured given the structure that np.argwhere() naturally returns but is that really the bottleneck here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the source vectors are just the same as in the other solution:

```
vectorA = np.array([np.nan, 1., 2., 3.,     np.nan, 5.,     np.nan, 7.,
    8., np.nan])
vectorB = np.array([0.,     1., 2., np.nan, 4.,     np.nan, 6.,     np.nan,
    8., np.nan])
```

You can do your task using *Pandasonic* **Index** and its *intersection* method.
It is even possible to write it as the following one-liner:

```
result = pd.Index(vectorA).intersection(vectorB)
```

The result is:

```
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 8.0], dtype='float64')
```

If you want the result as a *Numpy* vector, append `.values` to the above code
and the result will be:

```
array([1., 2., 8.])
```

The advantage of this method is that you avoid any list comprehensions,
so this code should run substantially faster than yours.
Check it on your own, on a bigger data sample.

Comment: Thanks! This does run much faster it seems, but it includes nan's in the result - any idea why that may be despite it not doing so in the smaller toy example?

a=np.random.normal(0,1,3000000); b=imbue_missing(a);
result = pd.Index(a).intersection(b);
print(result)
>>> Float64Index([   0.5743935953457322,   
                  -0.7174387885462609,   nan,
                  1.427427325840093,  -0.13925936048882145],
             dtype='float64', length=2791570)

Also, I prefer to get the indices where these values are returned, not the values themselves. Is there a built-in way to?

Comment: Note that my source data does contain *NaN*, as "true" *np.nan* values and the result doesn't. Maybe your source vector contains "nan" as a **string**? If this is the case, start with replacing "nan" strings with "true" *NaN* values and then run my code.